# Extracting two substrings from a string with a predictable format

Tags: c

I am trying to extract two substrings from a string:

```
char test[] = "today=Monday;tomorrow=Tuesday";
char test1[20];
char test2[20];

sscanf(test, "today=%s;tomorrow=%s", test1, test2);
```

When I print out today, I get Monday but also the rest of the string. I want test1 to be Monday and I want test2 to be Tuesday. How do I use sscanf correctly?

Answer (score 3):

The key is to tell `sscanf` where to stop.
In your case that would be at the semicolon.
If you don't specify then `%s` says read until the next whitespace, as @mkasberg mentions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  char *teststr = "today=Monday;tomorrow=Tuesday";
  char today[20];
  char tomorrow[20];

  sscanf(teststr, "today=%[^;];tomorrow=%s", today, tomorrow);
  printf("%s\n", today);
  printf("%s\n", tomorrow);

  return 0;
}
```

Produces:

```
Monday
Tuesday
```

---

Edit:
You may find useful this alternative using `strtok`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
  const char teststr[] = "today=Monday;tomorrow=Tuesday";
  const char delims[] = ";=";
  char *token, *cp;
  char arr[4][20];
  unsigned int counter = 0;
  unsigned int i;

  cp = strdup(teststr);
  token = strtok(cp, delims);
  strcpy(arr[0], token);

  while (token != NULL) {
    counter++;
    token = strtok(NULL, delims);
    if (token != NULL) {
        strcpy(arr[counter], token);
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    printf("arr[%d]: %s\n", i, arr[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
arr[0]: today
arr[1]: Monday
arr[2]: tomorrow
arr[3]: Tuesday
```

Answer (score 0):

When the %s tag is used, sscanf reads until the next whitespace is found, according to this documentation: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/

So, for example, you could change your string to

```
char test[] = "today=Monday tomorrow=Tuesday";
```

Comment: Hmm, how could I do it if I can't modify the original test string?

Comment: If you can't modify the original string, try using a combination of while loops.  Loop over characters in test until you encounter an =.  Then start saving chars to test1 until you encounter a ;.  Repeat similarly for test2.

Comment: Like this: `int i = 0; while(test[i] != '=') {i++}; int j=0; while(test[i] != ';') {test1[j] = test[i]; i++; j++}`

Comment: Alternatively, replace all ';' with ' ' in the original string and then use sscanf as you were.